# Docker windows 10 can't ping LAN ip

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a container in my Docker under Windows 10.
From this container, i'm not able to ping a ip in my lan :

```
root@d02eb989ee4e:/home/wwwroot# ping api.xxx.be
PING kust.xxx.be (192.168.0.147) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- kust.xxx.be ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4178ms
```

The DNS resolution is ok (api.xxx.be => kust.xxx.be => 192.168.0.147) but I have 100% packet loss.

When I ping a other ip/site on the net (like Google) than the ping is ok.

```
root@d02eb989ee4e:/home/wwwroot# ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (172.217.168.228) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ams15s40-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.168.228): icmp_seq=1 ttl=37 time=19.0 ms
64 bytes from ams15s40-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.168.228): icmp_seq=2 ttl=37 time=23.6 ms
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 19.051/21.370/23.689/2.319 ms
```

Why I'm loosing 100% of my packets when I ping a ip in the lan ?
I have made the test from my host and I was able to ping the same ip.

When I try with curl than I have a timeout response

Here is my Docker-composer file :

```
version: '3'
services:
  apache:
    build: .docker/apache
    container_name: ocr_apache
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - '.docker/config/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled'
      - '.:/home/wwwroot'
    depends_on:
      - php
  php:
    build: .docker/php
    container_name: ocr_php
    volumes:
      - '.:/home/wwwroot'
```

It's a very simple PHP/Apache containers.
I try to make the ping from the PHP container.

Thank you

Comment: does your docker container have port access to through your  local machine? i.e.  `80`

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer.
I have just added my docker composer file.

Comment: what happens when you try to run `docker run .docker/php -p 80:80` - does it return the ping or does it drop?

Comment: $ docker run .docker/php -p 80:80
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: invalid reference format.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.

Comment: try to build the image with `docker build -t <your-tag> .docker/php` - then pass the image into `docker run` like `docker run <image> -p 80:80`

Comment: tried `--network="host"`?

Comment: $ docker run testphp -p 80:80
[25-Jan-2019 12:22:30] ERROR: the global prefix '80:80' does not exist or is not a directory
[25-Jan-2019 12:22:30] ERROR: FPM initialization failed

Comment: @Mayur :where ? 
Thanks you

Comment: @Jean-marcStrauven while starting container!